How to integrate google location api with flutter
I'm trying to connect google location api with flutter and I'm getting below error:
D/MapsInitializer(15510): preferredRenderer: null
D/zzcc    (15510): preferredRenderer: null
I/zzcc    (15510): Making Creator dynamically
W/ziparchive(15510): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000001ad/DynamiteLoader.uncompressed.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive(15510): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000001ad/DynamiteLoader.uncompressed.dm': No such file or directory
I/DynamiteModule(15510): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_core_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_core_dynamite:241610202
I/DynamiteModule(15510): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_core_dynamite, version >= 241610202
V/DynamiteModule(15510): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/System  (15510): ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
D/nativeloader(15510): Configuring clns-6 for other apk . target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~aDJz21s4KF00HrE2fHyMrw==/com.google.android.gms-ok87zpsyyDDP-MOdQOTVYA==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~aDJz21s4KF00HrE2fHyMrw==/com.google.android.gms-ok87zpsyyDDP-MOdQOTVYA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
W/obile.asset.tns(15510): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/VMStack;->getStackClass2()Ljava/lang/Class; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/nativeloader(15510): Configuring clns-7 for other apk . target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000197/dl-MapsCoreDynamite.integ_241610202100400.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand
I/native  (15510): I0000 00:00:1719357308.066152   15510 jni_init.cc:8] Initializing JNI...
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.apptricity.mobile.asset.tns, sha256=[7090f01d4f12a801e1ecf56b2a8ca456decdf75a240426b2aa316f57bb08ba20], atk=false, ver=242334038.true (go/gsrlt)
I have added this in my AndroidManifest.xml under src/main in the application tag.:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="Key"/>

here is my code:
class AssetLocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String displayLabel;
  final double? longitude;
  final double? latitude;

  AssetLocationScreen(
      {required this.displayLabel, this.longitude, this.latitude});

  @override
  State<AssetLocationScreen> createState() => _AssetLocationScreenState();
}

class _AssetLocationScreenState extends State<AssetLocationScreen> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  bool _locationPermissionGranted = false;

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    mapController = controller;

    var status = await Permission.location.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      var result = await Permission.location.request();
      if (result.isGranted) {
        // Update the state to reflect permission status
        setState(() {
          _locationPermissionGranted = true;
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _locationPermissionGranted = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LatLng position = LatLng(widget.latitude ?? 0.0, widget.longitude ?? 0.0);
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 60.0, left: 60.0, right: 60.0, bottom: 20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(2, 153, 204, 1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Inquiry',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 4),
                Text(
                  widget.displayLabel,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                Text(
                  'Location',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: position,
                    zoom: 14.0,
                  ),
                  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                  myLocationEnabled: _locationPermissionGranted,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: _locationPermissionGranted,
                  /*    markers: Set<Marker>.of([
                    Marker(
                      markerId: MarkerId('assetLocation'),
                      position: position,
                    ),
                  ]),*/
                ),

                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        Color.fromRGBO(70, 206, 252, 1),
                        Color.fromRGBO(0, 54, 120, 1),
                      ],
                      stops: [0.2486, 0.833],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Could you confirm if you're using the Latest renderer?

this is the log: oogle Play services client version: 18020000
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(24204): Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10356; state: ENABLED
I/Google Android Maps SDK(24204): Google Play services package version: 242334038
I/Google Android Maps SDK(24204): Google Play services maps renderer version(maps_core): 241610202
D/MapsInitializer(24204): loadedRenderer: LATEST
D/zzcc    (24204): preferredRenderer: null
I/Google Android Maps SDK(24204): Google Play services package version: 242334038
